# Writing a program to obtain the elements of a two dimensional array in row order from first to last

Tags: java, arrays, element

Will this work? Or do I need to change anything. I tried to run this on eclipse but I was not getting any response. And also I don't understand this question very much so if anyone can modify this code than it would be great!

```
    Public class Array
{
public static void main (String []args)
        {  
        int total = 0;     
        int array[][] = new int[3][5];
            //give array some value
            for(int i = 0; i < 3 ; i++)
            for(int j = 0; j<6 ; i++)
                        array[i][j]=(i+1)*(j+1)


    //Use for -each for to display and total the values
            For (int x [] : array) {
                    For(int y[] : x){
                            System.out.println(“Value is  : + y”);
                            total=total + y;
                                          }
                                   }
     System.out.println(“Total of array elements : ” + total);
  } //end main


}//end class Array
```

Thanks

Comment: I'd be surprised if this compiles at all... `For` instead of `for`, fancy double quotes instead of straight quotes... Also, Java style suggests you use `int[] x` instead of `int x[]`.

Comment: "And also I don't understand this question very much" - if *you* don't understand the question, how are we meant to? And surely to answer "will this work" you should at least see if your code *compiles* first.

Answer (score 2):

No, that won't work.

It won't work for two classes of reasons:

1. It won't compile because there are several fundamental syntax issues.
2. If those are corrected it will fail with an exception when it runs for various reasons.

It also has maintainability and style issues. Details:

Compilation issues:

- It's `public`, not `Public`. Capitalization matters in Java.
- It's `for`, not `For`.
- You muse use normal straight quotes (`"`), not fancy quotes (`“`).
- You must end statements with semicolons (`array[i][j] = (i + 1) * (j + 1)` is missing the `;` at the end).
- Your inner `for` statement in the second pair of loops, `for (int y[]: x)`, is incorrect: `y` should be `int`, not `int[]`.

Runtime issues:

- Your inner loop assigning values increments `i` when it should increment `j`: `for(int j = 0; j<6 ; i++)` (note the `i++` at the end). This will cause an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because `i` gets too high fairly quickly.
- (If you fix the above.) In that same loop, you're using `j < 6`, which means the code will throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when `j` is `5`.
- The line `System.out.println("Value is: +y");` (I've corrected the quotes there) will always output the text `"Value is +y"`. If your goal was to to output `y`, it (and the `+` in front of it) would have to be *outside* the quotes.

Maintainability and style issues:

- In your loops, use `array.length` rather than `3`, and use the subarray's length rather than `5`. That way, when you change the array, your loops don't break.
- In general, use `int[][] array`, `int[] x`, and such. The `[]` should go with the type.
- In general, use `{` and `}` even when your block is only one statement long.
- Use consistent, reasonable indentation to make your code readable — to yourself and to others.

I think that about covers it. That should give you the information you need to correct your code, hopefully understand it a bit better, and get it running. Enjoy!